# How to Solve the ERROR: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, cpu, perfmon

**i set up all the things** 
Your setup at client and server side is correct.

But you have not mentioned opening of port # 4444. So it is most probably the cause of issue.

In order to make it work, Your port#4444 should be visible to JMeter client machine.

To verify if it is visible or not. you can use..

http://www.canyouseeme.org/
http://portchecker.co/
If it is not visible from Client machine, then you will need to open it. Visit these links to learn how to open port.

http://www.wikihow.com/Open-Ports
or you may use following from command line

now i run the jmeter for cpu testing but 
 **ERROR: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect in jmeter**

Answer (score 1):

From what I can figure out from your question you're trying to use [JMeter with PerfMon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) in order to check CPU usage while your test is running.

In order to get this up and running your need to:

1. Install and launch [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) on the server you want to monitor
2. Verify the connectivity between the machine where PerfMon Server Agent is running and the machine where PerfMon Metrics Collector is located by trying to send `test` command using [`telnet`](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026) or equivalent. You should see `Yep` message as the response.

   [image: JMeter Test PerfMon]

   If you see `Yep` message in the terminal - you're good to go.

   If not - you need to ensure that you open port `4444` for incoming TCP and/or UDP traffic in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)). If your server is running in i.e. [Amazon Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) you'll additionally need to open the port in [Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html). If you're not capable of doing this yourself - contact your network administrator or DevOPS or whoever is managing the infrastructure.

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)